# How to run code in a server side (asp.net) button in a facebook application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am develop a facebook application. I was added a server side or (asp.net) button to do something ,but it isn`t work. when i click the button nothing take place at all and it isn`t back to the server.
can anybody help me ,please?

thanks in advance

this is my code

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label2.Text = "OK";
    }

Comment: all controls I am using is runat server. I am using FacebookSDK_V4.2.1  the button works exactly in the normal pages  , but it does not work in pages where CanvasAuthorizer is defined as following:
        public FacebookApp fbApp;  
        fbApp = new FacebookApp();
        authorizer = new CanvasAuthorizer(fbApp);

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your aspx button tag you have the runat="server" attribute, like so:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Not OK" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
```